# Pandas Dataframe and Converting DateTime Objects

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I have multiple datettime columns in my dataframe and when I export the datetime to csv, I need to convert the datetime from Month/Day/Year to Month/Year.  Is it possible to do this?

I was trying this:

```
if date_mask == "MMM":
    df[name].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b %Y'))
else:
    df[name].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m %Y'))
```

When I look at the exported CSV I still see the old datetime values.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

**##########################################################**

**Solution**

```
def modify_date(x):
    try:
        if pd.isnull(x) == False:
            return x.strftime('%b %Y')
        else:
            print pd.NaT
    except:
        return pd.NaT

df = pd.DateFrame.from_records(<some list from database>)

df[name] = df[name].apply(modify_date)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Assign it back to `df[name]`: `df[name] = df[name].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m %Y'))`

Comment: You need to assign the results of the `apply` method, because it doesn't modify the `DataFrame` inplace.

Comment: @bernie i'll give it a try!

Comment: Which application did you use to view the csv file (e.g. Excel)?  Is it the raw CSV, or a date-parsed version?

Comment: @bernie it seems to fail when the column value is NaT (null).

Comment: @Alexander - raw CSV

Comment: Josh, what value would you like there when there is NaT?

Comment: @bernie - can I just leave it  NaT or None?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think you'll need some kind of a datetime value in there. You could make it `dt.date(0001,1,1,0,0,0)` and then replace that with `''` after doing the `.strftime()`

Comment: As for `NaT`, maybe try `df[name].dt.strftime(...)` instead of `apply`.

Comment: @bernie - the df[name] = df[name].apply() is not assigning the values back to the old column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
def modify_date(x):
    try:
        if pd.isnull(x) == False:
            return x.strftime('%b %Y')
        else:
            print pd.NaT
    except:
        return pd.NaT

df = pd.DateFrame.from_records(<some list from database>)

df[name] = df[name].apply(modify_date)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @bernie - this answer is very slow, my script goes from 1 minute to 4  minutes over 400K records with 6 datetime columns.  Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: Doesn't this work: `df[name] = df[name].dt.strftime('%b %Y')`?

Comment: @ptrj: It doesn't because he has NaTs in there.

Comment: @josh1234: it's slow because it's being done in Python as opposed to C. See this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38711326/42346

Comment: @bernie The thing is this takes care of NaTs (at least in pandas 0.18.1). If not, then maybe the dtype is a problem and `pd.to_datetime()` should be applied first.

Comment: Oh really. Oh I see.